# How to authenticate user and save their details

Tags: typescript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I've tried reading angularfire2 docs, and have come up till here. My authentication service call angularfire.auth.login. I've subscribed to this function and I want to save the userinfo that is returned, to the database.

Typescript compiler returns error:

`Error: Typescript found the following errors:
  /Users/macbook/dev/app/kichenclub/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-nMnfGgj9.tmp/0/src/app/auth.service.ts (12, 25): Property 'displayName' does not exist on type 'FirebaseAuthState'.`

and the same for all 'displayName'.

Am I in the right direction, even? How else to work this out.

authentication.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private userModel= this.af.database.object('/users');
  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe((auth) => {
      console.log(auth);
      this.userModel.set({
        uid: auth.uid,
        firstName: auth.displayName.split(0, auth.displayName.lastIndexOf(' ')),
        lastName: auth.displayName.split(auth.displayName.lastIndexOf(' '), auth.displayName.length),
        displayPic: auth.photoURL,
        provider:auth.provider
      });
    });
  }

  public loginFacebook (): void {
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup
    })
  }
}
```

Let me know, if any further information is required.

Lastly, thanks for stopping by. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the angularfire2 source code on GitHub and I examined the FirebaseAuthState Interface, you can find it [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/auth/auth_backend.ts). You can see that the TypeScript Interface itself does not have a property called 'displayName'. However it does show that there a nullable types that appear to hold the data you are looking for

```
export interface FirebaseAuthState {
  uid: string;
  provider: AuthProviders;
  auth: firebase.User;
  expires?: number;
  github?: CommonOAuthCredential;
  google?: GoogleCredential;
  twitter?: TwitterCredential;
  facebook?: CommonOAuthCredential;//<---based on your code I think this is what you're looking for.
  anonymous?: boolean;
}
```

I think you will want to take a closer look at the auth.facebook property. In order to get a better look at the details, I would simply comment out the code in your subscribe method and just write the object to the console and take a look at it in your browser using browser developer tools. For example something like this.

```
this.af.auth.subscribe((auth) => {
  console.log(auth);
  //this.userModel.set({
    //uid: auth.uid,
    //firstName: auth.displayName.split(0, auth.displayName.lastIndexOf(' ')),
    //lastName: auth.displayName.split(auth.displayName.lastIndexOf(' '), auth.displayName.length),
    //displayPic: auth.photoURL,
    //provider:auth.provider
  //});
});
```

This will allow you to look closer at the data inside auth.facebook.

Comment: Thanks @dan. Actually, I went through logging and getting through. Actually, I missed that `auth.auth` actually holds the data. My bad. I guess, I was high on caffeine, to miss that. :p